# Parsing data inside CDATA element

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

i need to parse a XML file that looks like this

```
1.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
2.<Root>
3.<Record>
4.<in><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><XML><Attribute AttrID="A">Test</Attribute>-<Attribute AttrID="B"> <![CDATA[Aap Noot Mies]]> </Attribute>]]></XML></in>
5.<out><![CDATA[]]></out>
6.</Record>
7.</Root>
```

I am getting a erro while parsing line number 4 Is there any way to escape a CDATA end token ( ]]> ) within a CDATA section in an xml document.

Comment: XML doesn't allow nested CDATA sections and it looks like the opening and closing of your outer CDATA aren't even properly formed.  Why do you have XML like this?  Is there a possibility to produce it differently?

Comment: Well can i handle it somehow so that my data gets proper for the parser and pickup the last ending tag of the cdata instead . I am using SAXParser.

Comment: The closest I can think of to "escaping" a `]]>` is to replace it with something like `]]]]><![CDATA[>` (i.e. end one CDATA section and immediately start another), but this is something that will have to be done at source - what you have there currently is not XML.

Answer (score 3):

Your input is not well formed there are several errors I think you need to fix whatever generated that to generate something more like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
<Record>
<in><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- - --><XML><Attribute AttrID="A">Test</Attribute>-<Attribute AttrID="B"> <![CDATA[Aap Noot Mies]]<![CDATA[> </Attribute></XML>]]></in>
<out><![CDATA[]]></out>
</Record>
</Root>
```

Note that the outer CDATA needs `<![CDATA[` not `<!CDATA[` the first use of `]]>` needs to be quoted (for example by stopping and starting the outer CDATA section as here). The outer `]]>` needs to be moved after the `</XML>` so that the end as well as the start of the element is quoted.

That makes the file technically well formed, although elements with name `XML` (or in general starting with `xml` in upper or lower case are *reserved* by the W3C for use in XML related specifications and should not be used in user XML files unless it is a specific element or attribute (such as `xmlns` defined by the W3C)

In addition I added a (quoted) comment around the dash after the XML declaration as if that CDATA section were extracted and made into an XML document it would make the resulting document non-well formed as only white space or comments and PIs are allowed before the first element.

Comment: Thanks David although i cant alter the source but a i guess i can manually handle it with my code .

Comment: Well the source just isn't XML so it needs to be edited with non-xml tools to make it so before it can be processed with an XML parser. It runs to one fatal syntax error every 10 characters or so which is quite an achievement:-)

Comment: I understand David . Thanks A lot anyways :)

Comment: I have edited the XML to make it valid , how can i handle it now .??